# Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu center align not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I am not able to align the dropdown to the center of the parent on which the dropdown is opened with hover. I have tried to text-align: center for the entire .nav .navbar li elements, and it doesn't work. I have tried to set margin and left: 50% for the entire ul.dropdown-menu that is the dropdown and it doesn't work. Here is the html code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="headerDropdowns">
  <li><div class="btn-toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btnCustom" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000">Our Difference</button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Made in the USA</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Human Grade</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Ingredients Fresh</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">USDA Meats</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Our Story</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Campare</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In which class dropdown-menu, or nav navbar-nav, should I do the aligment, and what should I set?

Comment: Demo and CSS please.

Answer (score 81):

You can use transform to avoid having to use fixed widths:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  left: 50%;
  right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

Answer influenced by http://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/

Comment: PaulHighten  You rock! Very nice solution.  (don't forget you need the `position: absolute;` in there somewhere...)  Thank-you for the link.

Comment: Update: I'm only able to make this work in the child content is half or less than half the width of the available parent container.

Comment: Does not work properly with narrow screens / wide dropdowns.

Comment: If those having problems can post fiddles I will have a look to see if I can help further

Comment: This worked beautifully for the issue I was having w/ multiple daynamic dropdowns.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this as long as you're willing to give the dropdown ul a fixed width. See code below:

```
.dropdown{text-align:center;}
.button, .dropdown-menu{margin:10px auto}
.dropdown-menu{width:200px; left:50%; margin-left:-100px;}
```

First 2 declarations are for visualization purposes, but the important part is the 3rd line. You'll need to define a width (in this case 200px) and then a `margin-left` equal to half the width. This will work with any width, no matter if the button is at the right, left or between elements (but of course you'll probably need some space for the `button` element)

You can [see a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/orr3cmgz/)

Comment: I have set the width of the dropdown to 140px and the margin to -70, and it doesn't work. I will add all of the css shortly i the edit. Actually nothing has changed when I applied these css settings.

Comment: Works for me, thank you so much for doing a fiddle here.

Answer (score 1):

The only, ugly way is to set the position depending on your needs like:

```
.dropdown-menu{
    right: -25px !important;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stefan_wave/nja0pujf/)

But thas not the way it should be used. Keep in mind that you have to adjust the setting for all media devices.

Answer (score 0):

This is what did the trick for me:

```
.dropdown-menu{
    left: -25% !important;
}
```

You might need to adjust the percentage value depending on your dropdown-menu's padding etc.