# position dropdown button and dropdown menu in center?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="dropup center-block">
            <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle center-block" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About Me<span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-header">Dropup stuff</li>
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

added `center-block` to both div and button, but unable to get the dropup menu positioned center.

A similar thing can be found at "Dropdown Position" in this [page](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp). The button is aligned left, but the menu is right. I'm able to align the menu right but not center.

Please help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A little trick add some css rules,`text-center` with `dropdown` class and `dropdown-menu-center` to the list.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28078054/6142097

```css
.dropdown-menu-center {
  left: 50% !important;
  right: auto !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0) !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <div class="dropdown text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-center">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think my solution is much more simpler than this one.. transform property wont be working on every browser and its not recommended to use important attribute without any need..

Comment: I was able to center a dropdown in my case with simply: `transform: translate(-50%);`

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you. I've used it for a Wordpress menu dropdown, and it works like magic!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a margin-left

```
 <div class="dropup center-block" style="margin-left: 49%;">
```

Comment: Also added `margin-left` to `"dropdown-menu`. `<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="margin-left:-5%;">`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is  to use 'dropdown-menu-center" class instead of 'center-block'.

Comment: you mean this `<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-center">`? Nope, it did not work. Morover, when I removed `center-block` from button class, the button too moved to the left.

Answer (score -1):

here is your solution
https://jsfiddle.net/7urwr62j/

```
 <div class="text-center">
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
<style>
.dropdown{
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```