# HTML/CSS problem with the dropdown menu not being centered under the button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

I'm trying to make the menu centered under the button. Currently, it's left-aligned.

Here is the code:

```css
.role_select {
    margin: auto;
}

#role_select > div {
    margin-top: 5%;
}

ul[aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1"] > li {
    text-align: center;
}

ul[aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1"] {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="role_select">
            <button
                class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
                type="button"
                id="dropdownMenuButton1"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="false"
            >
                Select Role
            </button>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                <li @click="id_drop(0)">MT-Almighty</li>
                <li @click="id_drop(1)">ST-Almighty</li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

E:

I've seen dropdown-menu-right and stuff, but there doesn't seem to be one for middle or center.

Comment: Now you have 13 rep. You can post images.

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE, thanks, but I still can't add it. I tried to use the 'link an image' option, but there was an error in the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was looking for the wrong thing.

[position dropdown button and dropdown menu in center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419705/position-dropdown-button-and-dropdown-menu-in-center)

I added a new class to the  ul tag which solved it.

Margin-top had to be eyeballed with pixels for some reason since percentage changed made the menu was lower than it should be when the screen became narrow.

```
    .dropdown-menu-center {
        left: 50% !important;
        right: auto !important;
        margin-top: 68px !important;
        text-align: center !important;
        transform: translateX(-50%) !important;
        position: fixed !important;
    }
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can either use a `margin left/right` property to center align the dropdown

or

- You can use the block method like this :

```
<div class="role_select">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle">
                Select Role
            </button>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>MT-Almighty</li>
                <li>ST-Almighty</li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

- define a width for `class="role_select"` so that `class="dropdown-menu"` can easily come within it and define `btn-secondary` `dropdown-menu` both classes display property as `display:block`. Then you can center align bothusing `margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center` like this :

```
.role{
  width:10%;/*20%,100px,....your wish so thatdropdown can eassily come */
}
.dropdown-menu{
  display:block;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  text-align:center
}
.btn-secondary{
  display:block;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  text-align:center
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. Here is what it looks like: https://imgur.com/a/vx4lbX9.

I mentioned that margin-left/right didn't work with the ul tag, which was what's misaligning.