# Center aligning Dropdown component in Bootstrap 4 not working properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have reviewed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25611198/4411757) which will help me to accomplish my ultimate goal (by tweaking CSS) but my question is regarding component and styling that bootstrap has provided us.

**Problem**: The dropdown button is aligned just as required but the dropdown menu is misaligned. Try resizing the window to verify small devices, tablet sizes.

Changing number of columns by modifying `col-sm-12` also helps a bit but the misalignment still persists on small devices.

Here's the **Minimal, Complete and Verifiable**: [JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/nirajpandkar/cbkcphnh/1/)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
            <div class="col-sm-12 align-self-center">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Select Category
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu"
                         aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">


                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Category1</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Category2</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Category3</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

The two classes which allow us to center align -

`justify-content-center` : 
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment

`text-center` : https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/typography/#text-alignment

**Question**:

1. Why don't the above classes apply to the dropdown menu but only to the dropdown button?
2. Are there are any helpful Bootstrap 4 styling classes that I'm missing that would fix that misalignment?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's because your dropdown menu is positioned absolutely - you need to overwrite it's styles and position it in the center rather than on the left:

```
.justify-content-center .dropdown-menu {
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cbkcphnh/2/)

Comment: Could you explain what the purpose of the translateX is doing for us? Just curious. This seems like it works well.

Comment: Works like a charm. So absolute positioning was the crux here.  Thanks for the propmt answer!

Comment: @DanielZuzevich because I have used left 50%, that wouldn't centre it, it would be too far right as it starts from the sub-menus left top corner, the translate just moves it backward on itself by half it's width (% translations are based on a percentage of itself)

Comment: Nice. thank you very much. Cool trick, never knew how to do that.